# Evaluate $\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}}$

Tags: arithmetic, exponentiation

I solved a question in the Manhattan GRE 5 pound book (specifically the 11th question in the Exponents and Roots section). I evaluated $\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}}$ as $5^{-2}$ and then $\frac{1}{25}$. But the solution given in the book evaluates it as $5^2$ which is $25$.
Can anyone explain this?

Comment: I agree with your answer.

Comment: You probably copied the problem wrong.

Comment: No, they have printed the expression (that I solved) in the question but they have solved the slightly different expression as shown by Joel.
It is a printing mistake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible that the book intended to write the expression
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}}}$$
This evaluates to
$$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}}}=\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5^2}}=5^2=25$$

Comment: That's it! They have printed the expression the way Peter Woolfitt has depicted it but they have solved the expression the way you have depicted it.
I hope this doesn't happen during the actual GRE :-(

Answer (score 2):

The explanation is that the book is in error (assuming the question is accurately stated).

$$\Large{\frac{\frac{1}{1}}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}}}=\Large{\frac{1}{\frac{1}{5^{-2}}}}=\frac{1}{5^{2}}=\frac{1}{25}$$

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.